# Django: Reverse not found. 'teachers_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm new in django. I am using this tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views, but can't get the right work of my application.
I created an app "education" in my "edusys" project. I'm trying to get the list of teachers from database and go to every teacher's page, where I'll be able to see their information from database.

I get the next error when I use "runserver":

[Reverse for 'teachers_detail' not found. 'teachers_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk7ad.png)

What am I doing wrong? I can't solve the problem myself and can't find the right answer in google.

My files of this project looks like this:

**education/models.py :**

```python
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Teachers(models.Model):
    tcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    department_s = models.ForeignKey('Departments', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    employee_post = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    academic_degree = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)

    GENDER_UNIT = (
        ('m', 'Мужчина'),
        ('f', 'Женщина'),
    )

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_UNIT)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.middle_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("teachers_detail", args=[str(self.tcode)])
```

**education/urls.py :**

from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

```
app_name = 'education'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^teachers/$', views.TeachersListView.as_view(), name='teachers'),
    #url(r'^teachers/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.TeachersDetailView.as_view(), name='teachers_detail'),
    url(r'^teachers/<int:pk>$', views.TeachersDetailView.as_view(), name='teachers_detail'),
]
```

**education/views.py :**

```python
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Teachers
from django.views import generic

def teachers_detail(request, pk):
    context = dict()
    return render(request, 'education/teachers_detail.html', context)

class TeachersListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Teachers
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'teachers_list' 
    template_name = 'education/teachers_list.html'


class TeachersDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Teachers
    #book_id=Teachers.objects.get(pk=Teachers.tcode)
```

**education/teachers_list.html :**

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container"><div class="col-12"><h1>Teachers list</h1></div></div>
<div class="container">
  
  {% if teachers_list %}
  
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          
          {% for Teachers in teachers_list %}
            <tr>
              <th scope="row"></th>
                <td><a href="{{ Teachers.get_absolute_url }}">{{ Teachers.last_name }} {{ Teachers.first_name }} {{ Teachers.middle_name|default_if_none:"" }}</a> ({{Teachers.department_s}})</td>
              <th scope="row"></th>
                <td>{{ Teachers.email }}</a></td>
              <th scope="row"></th>
                <td><a href="profile.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Профиль</a></td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        
        </tbody>
      </table>
    
  {% else %}
    <p>list is empty.</p>
  {% endif %}
</div> 
{% endblock %}
```

**education/teachers_detail.html :**

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ Teachers.last_name }} {{ Teachers.first_name }} {{ Teachers.middle_name }}</h1>

  <p><strong>email:</strong> {{ Teachers.email }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>department:</strong> {{ Teachers.department_s }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>employee post:</strong> {{ Teachers.employee_post }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>academic dehree:</strong> {{ Teachers.academic_degree }}</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Judging from the URI on your error page `/system/teachers/` I assume `education.urls` is included in a different urls.py? If that `include()` has a namespace argument, then `reverse('teachers_detail')` would be missing its namespace component.

Comment: @elyas what do you mean? I'm not sure I understood what you said

Comment: Is this line `path('/system/', include('education.urls'))` in a different urls.py file (not education/urls.py) somewhere in your project? If so, is there a [namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#include)?

Comment: @elyas yeah, it looks like you said: path('system/', include('education.urls'))

Comment: You might be mixing old and new URL definitions. In your urls.py try `from django.urls import path` and `path('teachers/<int:pk>', views.TeachersDetailView.as_view(), name='teachers_detail'),`

Comment: @elyas I am already using this include :( Is there any big difference between "path" and "url" in the urls files?

Comment: Yes there's a big difference. The use of [path converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) in angle brackets like `<int:pk>` is only supported using `path`

Comment: @elyas oh, I still get this error even after changed the "url" to "path". Still doesn't work :(((

Answer (score 0):

As per urls and models.py file problem lies in get_absolute_url method as url is expecting a keyword argument named **pk** while you are supplying an **args** in **get_absolute_url** **ie.args=[str(self.tcode)]**.Kindly change the same as below.

updated one:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("teachers_detail",kwargs = {'pk': self.tcode })
```

Old one:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("teachers_detail", args=[str(self.tcode)])
```

Note: Also as per ulrs.py the pk should be a integer value while as per model tcode is primary key and its a char field you can either use the correct field type or update the url keyword argument.I mean to say both should be in sync to avoid any explicit type casting.

```
url(r'^teachers/<int:pk>$', views.TeachersDetailView.as_view(), name='teachers_detail'),
```

Comment: I did what you said, but there's no changes yet. I get the same error "Reverse for 'teachers_detail' not found. 'teachers_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.". I really don't know what to do :(

Comment: @AlexMercer: you getting same error on runserver command or when hit http://127.0.0.1:8000/teachers/ url?

Comment: Change : url(r'^teachers/<int:pk>$', views.TeachersDetailView.as_view(), name='teachers_detail') to----------------------->
path('teachers/<int:pk>/', TeachersDetailView.as_view(), name='teachers_detail'),

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the `teachers_detail` URL path taking an integer parameter (`<int:pk>`) when the `Teachers` model has a custom primary key (`tcode`) and it is a string.

The following `path` should work (I tested it with the rest of your code):

```py
path('teachers/<str:tcode>', views.TeachersDetailView.as_view(), name='teachers_detail')
```

Comment: I did it... It's not working yet :( I don't understand why django shows error during template rendering in base html template (but there's no mistakes in base html template?)

Comment: it shows error in line 0 of base html template

Comment: Some versions of Django return a template error incorrectly. Open shell `manage.py shell` and try `from education.models import Teachers; Teachers.objects.first().get_absolute_url()` - it'll help narrow down whether the URL path is still causing the error. And double-check that the URL has `<str:tcode>` and not `<int:pk>`